# Cross-platform table of locales

Tags: c++, formatting, cross-platform, locale

I was testing some of the new `locale` stuff provided by C++11 like `std::put_money` to get used to their use. I was thinking that would be nice to show a large number printed as currency for all the countries supported by the standard library:

```
const char *Locales[] =
{
    "English_Australia.1252",
    "en_EN",
    "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    / ...
    // lots of lots of worldwide locales
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (const char **Locale = std::begin(Locales); Locale != std::end(Locales); ++Locale)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss.imbue(std::locale(*Locale))

        std::cout << *Locale << ' '
                  << std::showbase << std::put_money(11223344556677889900) << '\n';
    }
}
```

I was shocked when realized that the locale names aren't standard at all, for my Visual Studio 10.0 under Windows 7 Professional (SP1) (Spanish locale machine) the locale names follows the format `Language_Region.charsetID` for example: `English_Australia.1252`, in my Linux machine (Debian 4.2.2) with gcc 4.2.3 the locales follows the same format but with two letters `xx_XX.UTF-8` (for example `es_ES.UTF-8`) and while trying code on Ideone the only locale that seems to accept is the `en_US.UTF-8`.

The most frustrating part is to try to get a standard, cross-platform table of supported locales, the best one I've found Googling around is [this one](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales) that lists locales for Windows and their equivalents in *no-Windows*, but lacks of lots of countries (like USA, Guatemala, Mexico...).

Another thing I've tried is to debug step-by-step the `std::locale` constructor with the hope of found the piece of code that says which locale name is valid and which one isn't. I was expecting a giant array of locale names (like the one in the example code) but I was frightened by the complexity of the the `std::locale` constructor and fled away.

So my questions are:

- Which is the best and most complete table of cross-platform locales that you know and use?
- How to know the locales supported by the running system? How to access to the supported locales list?

Extra questions:

- Why the locale names aren't standard (granting a cross-platform source code)?
- Which locale system is used by Ideone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On UNIX-y systems, you get the list of locales by running `locale -a`, which is also recommended by `man setlocale`. I don't think that the C library even has a list of locales, because it looks them up at run-time in `/usr/lib/locale`.

In essence, this means that you can't know the locale list at compile time, because it is a runtime feature of your target system.